# Studio wont see my phone, USB Driver insatlled And Developer options on

Tags: android

I have a LG g styles smart phone witch is in MTP mode
When I click on run app, it says NO USB devices 
When I googled this it seems like all the answers where to install the driver and turn on debugger options.
I followed the directions on Goolges website to  install the driver, in witch it all ready was, driver for LG g styles.  My phone has the developer options on.

I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO??????

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities, one of which maybe your USB connection mode is the PTP mode but not MTP mode (which can be change on your phone)

Comment: It works on my frineds computer, so im assuming that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enabled Debugging via USB on your Phone?
Settings->Developer Settings...
Yes my phone works on my friends computer not mine

Answer (score 0):

I know it might sound a bit obvious, but have you uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled it? You might have changed some settings without realizing it.